# Thread#terminate and handling SIGTERM

Tags: ruby, multithreading, signals

Here's a simplified version of some code I wrote:

```
class InfiniteLoop
  def run
    trap('SIGTERM') do
      puts 'exiting'
      exit
    end
    loop {}
  end
end
```

If I run:

```
InfiniteLoop.new.run
```

I can `ctrl+c` and get:

```
exiting
```

However, when I do this:

```
t = Thread.new { InfiniteLoop.new.run }
sleep 1
t.terminate
```

I don't see:

```
exiting
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? I'd like to have the same behavior when terminating the thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sending a SIGTERM signal (via ctrl+c) the trap block is not executed.
See also the Kernel method:

```
at_exit { puts 'exiting' }
```

Answer (score 3):

`trap('SIGTERM')` will only respond to the signals sent from OS land.

`Thread#terminate` is ruby code that will kill the thread.

I don't know of a way to specify behavior for a thread to take before it is killed. That might be interesting. But I don't think it exists, because the semantics of `Thread#kill/terminate/join` wouldn't really allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `trap("EXIT")`. SIGTERM is sent by ctrl-C or a kill command. From the ruby docs:

> The special signal name “EXIT” or signal number zero will be invoked just prior to program termination.

Comment: Actually Ctrl-C sends SIGINT